# Is this sentence grammatically correct in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, meaning-in-context

> My instincts tell me that you won't refuse me *this one time*.

Is the sentence above grammatically correct?  I am a bit doubtful about the phrase in italics - *this one time*.

*Context*: I am asking for a favor from someone and I believe that they won't refuse this time (since last time they did).  Is it good to use the above sentence?

Comment: I think your reasoning is good, yes, "this one time" would mean maybe that he has been frustratingly refused in the past, OR that he is asking for this one opportunity rather pressingly and that if granted won't ask for anything more in the future. For example, "I beg you, grant me this opportunity just this one time, and I'll ask nothing of you again."

Comment: @Zebrafish, yes, what you say makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: It may be grammatically correct, but *this once* would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, so you mean _"My instincts tell me that you won't refuse me this once."_

Comment: Yes, where *this* is related to the occasion and not to what is not refused. That is, *one time* is unidiomatic and *once* is preferred for those two words. If you wanted to add *this* referring to the request itself ("You won't refuse me this [thing]"), then you would end up with "...you won't refuse me this this once," and a comma could be inserted between the two *this*es.

Comment: To me, your sentence is fine but not at all for the reason you state - although of course, there’s almost nothing to work with.

I suggest that either it’s wholly irrelevant or logically and historically, that means rather “I believe they won't refuse because I haven’t asked before, and won’t again.”

By the way, please don’t swap terms like “you” and “they”. Either might be suitable but switching is merely confusing.